# Selling link to an external site as product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, downloadable, virtual-products

We want to include some products which are actually held in an external site - however, they're not files, just pages within the external site. The external site manages authentication, access etc. and we just want to use Magento to sell a product which consists of a link to the remote site.

Downloadable products seemed to be the best option, but these are tailored towards downloadable files and so try to download a file from the supplied link.

Any suggestions on how we can do this?

Answer (score 4):

Downloadable products are made for this. You can choose between an uploaded file or an URL for each downloadable item of the product:

[image: Screenshot]

### Update: I was wrong

Magento proxies a download to the given URL instead of redirecting the customer, so some customization is necessary. I would still go with the downloadable product and add a new download type besides "File" and "URL", let's call it "Redirect"

1. **Define new link type**

   Edit the form HTML in
   `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml` (copy the file to a custom admin theme and modify it). Create a new option for the `downloadable[link][{{id}}][type]` input called "redirect" (below "file" and "url"). There might be a more elegant way to change the template without this override, using JavaScript instead.
2. **Handle new link type**

   Create a new controller for the "downloadable" route, using `before="Mage_Downloadable"` to override Mage_Downloadable_DownloadController::linkAction(). I would extend the original controller and just override the `_processDownload($resource, $resourceType)` method with something like this:

   ```
   protected function _processDownload($resource, $resourceType)
   {
       if ($resourceType === 'redirect') {
           //TODO: redirect to $resource
           return;
       } else {
           return parent::_processDownload($resource, $resourceType);
   }
   ```

Comment: My understanding is that if I supply a link there, it's a link to a file held on an external site. I've tried setting up the link to the website using that and after making a test purchase and going to downloadable products, I get an error saying 'An error occurred while getting the requested content. Please contact the store owner.'An error occurred while getting the requested content. Please contact the store owner.

Comment: I double checked and you are right, Magento proxies a download to the given URL instead of redirecting the customer. You will need to add a custom download type...

Comment: Please see updated answer.